# Проверка на существование файлов + загрузка новых php

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть папка, в папке есть 3 файла с названиями `0.jpg`, `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`.
Я загружаю файлы и переименовую их на порядковый номер.
Если в input было выбрано 3 файла то их порядковые номера такие же как и названия файлов в папке.
Как я могу обойти эту проблему, и если в папке есть файл `0.jpg` и нет файла `1.jpg` присвоить имя данному файлу `1.jpg`?

```
$count_files = count($_FILES["files"]['name']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count_files; $i++) {
   $exists_file = $i.".jpg";
   if (file_exists($exists_file)) {

   } else {

   }
   $name[$i] = $i.".jpg";
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$i], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/files/".$name[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $file) {
   $filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/files/" . $i . ".jpg";

   while (file_exists($filename)) {
        $filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/files/" . (++$i) . ".jpg";
   }

   move_uploaded_file($file, $filename);
}
```

Но я бы так в жизни не стал делать. Время выполнения функции будет зависеть от количества файлов. Генерирование имени файла было бы предпочтительнее. Даже `microtime()` для имени файла выглядит совершенством

Comment: `microtime()` незачем, т.к. максимум 5 файлов

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин, пять файлов за раз заливаются или 5 файлов всего в каталог заливаются? Это, знаете ли, две большие разницы

Comment: 5 файлов всего в каталоге может быть.